# How to refresh MS Access database in Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I'm wondering how to refresh database after inserting a new row without reopening whole application. I want to be able to see new data in next steps of my application. I can't find any solution, so i would be happy if you post the example. Of course if it is possible.
Here is my connection method

```
    try{
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    String db = "jdbc:odbc:FlowValves";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is one of my inserting methods.

```
    String sql = "select * from Typy";
    try{
        ResultSet result;
        result = st.executeQuery(sql);
        result.moveToInsertRow();

        String stringNazwa = (String)nazwaZaworuField.getText();
        result.updateString("Typ", stringNazwa);

        String stringDN = (String)dnZaworuField.getText();
        result.updateString("DN", stringDN);

        String stringPN = (String)pnZaworuField.getText();
        result.updateString("PN", stringPN);

        String stringIndeks = (String)indeksField.getText();
        result.updateString("Indeks", stringIndeks);

        result.insertRow();
        result.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wprowadzono dane", "Komunikat", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for inserting looks correct (although I would use an insert statement instead of using `moveToInsertRow()` )

You should be able to requery the database and put the new data on the screen:

```
String sql = "select * from Typy";
ResultSet result;
result = st.executeQuery(sql);

while( result.next() ){

   sting indeks = result.getString( "indeks" );
   // etc.

   // do something with the new data

}
```